# Unable to resolve this dependecy for curl in solaris 10

Tags: curl, solaris, solaris-10

i am trying to install curl on solaris 10.

I have installed the curl packages with other dependencies as

```
application SMCcurl                          curl
application SMClgcc346                       libgcc
application SMClibidn                        libidn
application SMCliconv                        libiconv
application SMClintl                         libintl
application SMClssh2                         libssh2
application SMCossl                          openssl
application SMCzlib                          zlib
```

When I tried to run the curl i am getting error as

```
/usr/local/bin # ./curl --version
ld.so.1: curl: fatal: libidn.so.11: version `LIBIDN_1.0' not found (required by file /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4)
ld.so.1: curl: fatal: libidn.so.11: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed
```

Searched for its solution, but no luck.

Ouput of the `ldd curl` command is

```
        libcurl.so.4 =>  /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4
        libidn.so.11 =>  /usr/local/lib/libidn.so.11
        libintl.so.8 =>  /usr/local/lib/libintl.so.8
        libsec.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libsec.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
        libiconv.so.2 =>         /usr/local/lib/libiconv.so.2
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
        libssh2.so.1 =>  /usr/local/lib/libssh2.so.1
        libssl.so.1.0.0 =>       /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 =>    /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
        librt.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/librt.so.1
        libz.so =>       /usr/local/lib/libz.so
        libgcc_s.so.1 =>         /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
        libidn.so.11 (LIBIDN_1.0) =>     (version not found)
        libavl.so.1 =>   /lib/libavl.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libaio.so.1 =>   /lib/libaio.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,Netra-440/lib/libc_psr.so.1
        /platform/SUNW,Netra-440/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
```

Can somebody please tell me how can resolve these dependency?

Comment: Have you considered how much easier this would be if you weren't still on Solaris 10. On Solaris 11 you would simply do `pkg install web/curl` and that's it!

Answer (score 4):

This might be because you have another package installed which provides a different version of the same library file. I came across the same issue today and found that I had a package called `SUNWgnu-idn` which installed libidn.so.11 in `/usr/lib/`.

> pvs -d /usr/lib/libidn.so.11
>
> ```
>     libidn.so.11;
> ```

Whereas the `libidn.so.11` which was part of the `SMClibidn` package was the right version.

> pvs -d /usr/local/lib/libidn.so.11
>
> ```
>     libidn.so.11;
>     LIBIDN_1.0;
> ```

Removing the conflicting package `SUNWgnu-idn` resolved the issue.

You could use the `pkginfo` tool to search for other installed packages.

> pkginfo | grep idn

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find out from the packager what version of libidn they used that defines that version.   You can see the versions provided by a library with the pvs command, such as `pvs -d /usr/local/lib/libidn.so.11`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this problem was solved, but I found, trying lynx, that there are 2 libraries with almost similar names:

```
bash-3.2# ldd /usr/local/bin/lynx
    libidn.so.11 =>  /usr/local/lib/libidn.so.11
    libidn.so.11 (LIBIDN_1.0) =>     (version not found)
    ...
```

The first libidn.so.11 cames from "SMClibidn" package versión 1.11, but no idea where I can get the one that cause the issue:
- "libidn.so.11 (LIBIDN_1.0) => (version not found)".

I do a try uninstalling versión 1.11 of "SMClibidn" and installing versión 1.22 and "voilà", lynx is working.

I hope this works also for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is look for package SUNWgnu-idn.  wget from UnixPackages is finding the libidn in /usr/lib first.  So set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to specify /usr/local/lib first when you need wget.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to install "libidn-1.11-sol10-sparc-local"

http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/sun-freeware/sparc/10/